# Где найти и как установить MASM?

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Где можно скачать MASM, установил Visual Studio 2015.
Но пока не получается найти MASM.

Моя цель - откомпилировать [zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/masmx86).

Comment: http://www.masm32.com/download.htm Не?

Comment: Смотрел данный сайт. Но как я понимаю MASM должен идти в комплекте с Visual Studio.

Comment: Вопрос снимаю, разобрался. переустановил Visual Studio 2015.